# ExtJS4 MVC Architecture walkthrough on sencha doc giving me errors

Tags: extjs4

I'm following the ExtJS4.0 [MVC Application Architecture walk through](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture) and modifying it to my own project as I go to make sure I get things right.  So far it's working perfectly. I've just completed the 'Defining a View' section and I'm about to start the 'Controlling the grid' section.  Before I do, I want to remove the console.log code as I don't want or need it for my own project.  I find I can replace it with an alert message but can't remove it all together without generating an error against ext-all-debug.js.

Here's my functioning code on the controller and the error it's generating after I remove the consol.log function. In the example doc, it's AM.controllers.list.

```
Ext.define('ChatAgent.controller.queues', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'
, views: [
    'queue.list'
]
, init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > panel': {
            render: this.onPanelRendered
        }
    });
}

, onPanelRendered: function() {
    console.log('The panel was rendered');
}
```

});

The error it generates is: 
'fireFn' is null or not an object

All I've removed is:

```
onPanelRendered: function() {
        console.log('The panel was rendered');
    }
```

So why the error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the event listener as well.  When the render event fires it is trying to call onPanelRendered which doesn't exist anymore.

If you aren't listening for any events, you don't even need to have that entire this.control block.  Comment this out and see what happens.

```
this.control({
    'viewport > panel': {
        render: this.onPanelRendered
    }
});
```